# Skia4Delphi text rendering issue in Android (FMX)

Tags: android, delphi, text, render, firemonkey

I'm having some sort of weird problem after using Skia in my project.
When enabling Skia and after drawing some text (Test Text, Hello World) in a VirtualListView
that text will appear like this:
Test Tex...
Hello wor...
Why there is some dots at the end of text?
And why the rest letters of the text is not finished but replaced with dots?
Example:
[image: https://freeimage.host/i/HK4cgKF]

I'm missing something?

Compiling the project in Windows 32/64 is working fine
but this problem persists in any Android build Debug/Release.

I've managed to temporary fix this issue by declaring the
ksVirtualListView before the Skia.FMX in the Uses list (Inside the project file)

```
program ExampleApp;

uses
System.StartUpCopy,
ksVirtualListView,
Skia.FMX,
FMX.Forms,
....
```

Drawing the text is now fine but the program started being slower, buggy and crashes sometimes!!
Any solution is appreciated.
thanks in advance.

How it appear in Windows:

[image]

How it appear in Android:

[image]

Using ksVirtualListView that came with Pentire:
https://github.com/gmurt/PentireFMX/blob/master/ksVirtualListView.pas

Comment: Usually, series of dots mean that part of the text did not fit in reserved space. What is Delphi version? Please show the setup of the components on the form.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg: I'm using Delphi 11, the reserved place for the text are big enough to hold it, going to capture an image..

Comment: First post updated.

Comment: Are you certain that the embedded text control holding the truncated text is wide enough?  Perhaps it's autosizing and calculating the width incorrectly.  I haven't analysed the code thoroughly, but I see that `TksVListItemTextObject.Create` sets `FAutoSize := True;`.

Comment: I fully agree with previous comment. In your edit you mention "Pentire". What is that? How is it related to your question. Actually, I need to ask you to provide a [mre] as this is not anymore answerable with just knowledge of how Delphi and Android works.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment I don't think this is caused by to narrow text control. That was my initial thought also. But after taking a closer look to the provided screenshot with correct and incorrect text rendering I noticed that text always get truncated after `(SM-`. In fact if you take a close look at 3rd item in list you can see that on screenshot that shows correct text rendering it is actually narrower than the shortened 1st item on the list that is shown on the next screenshot that shows incorrect text rendering.

Comment: @SilverWarior, that doesn't indicate that it's not too narrow a control.  If each control is autosizing, then a miscalculation of the size of, say, the hyphen, could cause the control to be just a few pixels too short, which would cause the text to truncate several characters short in order to leave room for the ellipsis.
Having said that, that doesn't seem to explain the truncated Itel and Super of the last item.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, the questioner explains that Pentire is the source of the list control he provides the link to.

Comment: @Philip Yes, after some googling I found the components, but I don't think I will install them. I still agree with you about possible miscalculation, but the problem could also be related to the "-" in the sense of forcing a division of the line in two perhaps related to a setting somewhere. OP could try replacing the hyphen to e.g., an underscore, for testing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the Pentire library itself that prevents the Skia4Delphi renderer from working in ksVirtualListView. A brief explanation: it created a TTextLayout at unit initialization, which is not ideal, as Skia4Delphi registers its own TTextLayout at canvas system initialization, which occurs when creating the first form, which is after the units initialization.

Anyway, I made the necessary changes and sent a pull request: https://github.com/gmurt/PentireFMX/pull/10

Just apply the changes to your Pentire source.

Comment: Did you test it? because i took your modifications and compiled but nothing has changed!

Comment: @JacckCooper Yes, I tested and works fine for me. Remember to revert to normal uses: uses System.StartUpCopy, FMX.Forms, Skia.FMX, ..;
If in any specific project the error persists, it would be good for you to try to make an example project reproducing the problem and create an issue on the Skia4Delphi github: https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi

Comment: After a lot of test and using your fix i've found that its working in other mobiles but in: Samsung Note 10+ its does not work and the problem persists. so i am going to post my problem here: github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi